# How to remove GNU screen directory movements from bash history

Tags: bash, display, history

Whenever I launch GNU screen, and do some directory movements  within it, I get tons of these kinds of lines appended to my bash history:

```
16469  2021-06-03 10:29:17 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton\0057BACKUPS'`"
16470  2021-06-03 10:29:37 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton'`"
16471  2021-06-03 10:29:39 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton\0057BACKUPS'`"
16472  2021-06-03 10:30:03 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton'`"
16473  2021-06-03 10:30:04 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton\0057BACKUPS'`"
16474  2021-06-03 10:30:10 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton'`"
16475  2021-06-03 10:30:11 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton\0057Charts'`"
16476  2021-06-03 10:30:45 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton'`"
16477  2021-06-03 10:30:47 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton\0057CloudCompare'`"
16478  2021-06-03 10:30:48 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton'`"
16479  2021-06-03 10:30:48 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton\0057Desktop'`"
16480  2021-06-03 10:30:49 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton'`"
16481  2021-06-03 10:30:50 - cd "`printf '%b' '\0057home\0057epatton\0057Exports'`"
```

I have `cd` appended to my `HISTIGNORE` bash variable, but this doesn't remove these lines. How can get rid of this cruft from my history?

Comment: `HISTIGNORE` patterns must match the whole line. Are you using `HISTIGNORE='cd *'` ?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I didn't know I could use bash shell patterns in `HISTIGNORE`